# Is having 2 GB of memory not enough with the new Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, safari, memory

I have the new Mac Mini with Mac OS X, with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5, with 2 GB of DDR3 memory at 1333 MHz, and a graphic card (Intel HD Graphics 3000 288 MB) that uses shared memory; the screen I am using has a resolution of 1600x900.
Periodically, Safari keeps freezing, and becoming unresponsive; all I can do is using Finder to force quitting it.

I am wondering if the memory I have (with the configuration I reported) is not sufficient, or it is simply a problem with Safari that can be resolved changing some of its settings. Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's Safari 5.1 you're in the same boat as a lot of people. The recommended suggestion is bail out and go to Chrome, but I like Safari so I've stuck with it. I've completely removed Flash from my system (I sandbox it in Chrome), I trash Safari's cache once a week, I completely shut Safari once every 4 hours, and I never have more than 10 tabs open at once. That keeps it relatively stable, but I'm probably going to move to Chrome as it's a bit much for one app.

Comment: +1 For Google Chrome. I have found even on Snow Leopard and Leopard that it has problems. Go Chrome!

Comment: Well I'm not Chrome's biggest fan in terms of UI, but it feels a lot faster than Safari so I think the speed will beat the gloss this time.